# .htaccess Redirection - Regex for *.html to wordpress urls

Tags: regex, wordpress, redirect

I've moved a static site (*.html) to wordpress with no changes to the urls.

Example:

domain.com/sample-url.html to

domain.com/sample-url/

There are over 200 pages and I'm tired of setting up redirection for each page. Is there a regex to put it on .htaccess file to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Does this regex work for you?

```
^(.+?)\.html$
```

Test: https://regex101.com/r/kks8Di/3/

Comment: I would like to put this in .htaccess file so it makes things easier.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: doesn't work after putting it in .htaccess file. any idea?

Comment: Can you share the content of .htaccess?